# Has anyone managed to configure Nautilus to show EXIF data?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, filesystem, python, multimedia

I followed instructions on the Ubuntu Forums to configure Nautilus to display additional information about image files - specifically, the EXIF data:

[[SOLVED] Adding mp3 info columns (e.g. bitrate, etc.) to nautilus list view]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7931669&postcount=38)

My machine is running Ubuntu 11.04. Having followed the procedure outlined in the above thread, I killed all instances of Nautilus, restarted Nautilus and selected the required  columns in the view preferences.

Unfortunately, the `Date` `EXIF Dateshot` `EXIF Image Size` `EXIF Software` `EXIF Flash` columns are blank. The only column that displays info is Image Size.

I followed the same procedure on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine at work, and the EXIF data is displayed.

I expected this method to work on 11.04, as none of the steps appear to be 10.xx specific.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this other script:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/music-and-exif-metadata-information-in.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6643803#post6643803

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The EXIF data columns have a bug in them, they should display information for files when you go to their properties. If they're not, then you should report it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

I do know that there is a version of the ~tag/EXIF plugin for Nautilus in the general Webupd8 ppa. It may be newer and/or have the bug(s) worked out.

Comment: is this possible in 11.10? as i tried the deb from webupd8 and it didnt work, its only for gnome 2.xx i take?